# Azure App Service not connecting

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have created new Azure API App Service – mytestapp, but when tried to open this below link from any browser
https://mytestapp.azurewebsites.net/

I get below error message
‘You do not have permission to view this directory or page.’

Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: It seems that you need to set the [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#default-documents). But I find it works correclty when I visit https://mytestapp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your response. i posted mytestapp just as an example. My link does not work.

Comment: Also reason for creating this API app service is to connect to Azure SQL Data Warehouse and return results in JSON or XML file, hope Azure API App Service would do that?